# Typo3 and changing CSS values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typo3, typoscript

I've got a problem with my website. I've got two divs, in the left one is the main content of the page and in the right div are some texts. When there is much content in one of those divs its height is bigger than the other div. So I tried to make the CSS value equal, but it didn't work at all. I have already doublechecked everything, the code, the file directory etc. I still don't see a mistake.
That's my Typoscript code to include jQuery and my JS-File:

```
# jQuery
includeJSlibs.jquery.external = 1
includeJSlibs.jquery = http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

# Javascript
includeJS.file1 = fileadmin/script.js
```

And that's my JS-file (script.js):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      var contentHeight = $(#content).css(["height"]);
      var sidebarHeight = $(#sidebar).css(["height"]);

      if (contentHeight > sidebarHeight) {
        $(#sidebar).height(contentHeight - 110);
      } else {
        $(#content).height(sidebarHeight + 110);
      }
    });
```

Edit: Almost forgot the CSS code:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 550px;
  min-height: 510px;
  border: 2px solid #b7cdd4;
  border-left-width: 2.5px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  float: left;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 242px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #b7cdd4;
  border-left-width: 2.5px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  margin-top: -91px;

}
```

Can anyone help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jquery` is not valid. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contentHeight = $('#content').css("height");
    var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').css("height");

    if (contentHeight > sidebarHeight) {
        $('#sidebar').height(contentHeight - 110);
    } else {
        $('#content').height(sidebarHeight + 110);
    }
});
```

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/7AyFc/) (Open the console and you will see the heights are there)

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've got a new code from someone where he uses var contentHeight = parseInt($('#content/sidebar').css("height"),10); which works fine. The post was deleted somehow...